# force close when close activities with broadcast receiver

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

i try to close activity from service, it works but after that force close 
here's my code in activity:

```
onCreate{
registerReceiver(abcd, new IntentFilter("xyz"));
}
```

and this

```
 private final BroadcastReceiver abcd = new BroadcastReceiver() {
         @Override
         public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
               finish();                                   
         }
 };

public void onDestroy() {

    unregisterReceiver(abcd);

}
```

and this to close activity in services

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent("xyz"));
```

logcat:

`08-12 15:05:01.032: E/AndroidRuntime(6975): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-12 15:05:01.032: E/AndroidRuntime(6975): android.app.SuperNotCalledException: Activity {com.example.sservice/com.example.sservice.run_service} did not call through to super.onDestroy()
08-12 15:05:01.032: E/AndroidRuntime(6975):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3330)
08-12 15:05:01.032: E/AndroidRuntime(6975):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3359)
08-12 15:05:01.032: E/AndroidRuntime(6975):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:143)
08-12 15:05:01.032: E/AndroidRuntime(6975):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1294)
08-12 15:05:01.032: E/AndroidRuntime(6975):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-12 15:05:01.032: E/AndroidRuntime(6975):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-12 15:05:01.032: E/AndroidRuntime(6975):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4963)
08-12 15:05:01.032: E/AndroidRuntime(6975):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-12 15:05:01.032: E/AndroidRuntime(6975):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-12 15:05:01.032: E/AndroidRuntime(6975):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
08-12 15:05:01.032: E/AndroidRuntime(6975):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
08-12 15:05:01.032: E/AndroidRuntime(6975):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)`

What's wrong? Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `super.onDestroy();` when overriding the onDestroy method.